# Convert XML to Dictionary

Tags: xml, powershell, dictionary, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Can someone please tell me how to convert the xml file to Dictionary using Powershell.

Here is my xml file looks like,

```
==>     <xml id="ATAT_Prod">
        <tag1>value1</tag1>
        <tag2>value2</tag2>
        </xml>
```

can someone suggest me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to load the content using the [Get-Content](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113310) cmdlet and cast it to `[xml]`. Use the `SelectNodes`cmdlet and a `xpath` expression to select all *descendants* and convert it to a *hashtable*:

```
$xml = [xml] (Get-Content 'YOUR_PATH_HERE')     
$xml.SelectNodes("descendant::node()") | ? Value | % { @{$_.ParentNode = $_.Value}  }
```

*Output:*

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                       
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                       
state                          Texas                                                                                                                                                       
environment                    Test                                                                                                                                                        
isEnabled                      False                                                                                                                                                       
filepath                       C:\xmlfile                                                                                                                                                  
test                           Test environement strings                                                                                                                                   
UAT                            UAT environment strings
```

**Edit**:
Here is a working example with a *dictionary*:

```
$myDictionary = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[System.String,System.String]"
$xml = [xml] (Get-Content 'YOUR_PATH_HERE')     
$xml.SelectNodes("descendant::node()") | ? Value | % $myDictionary.Add($_.ParentNode.ToString(), $_.Value)  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jisaak. It is working as expected. Can you tell me hashtable and dictionary are different right? if these are different, Can you suggest me how to convert to dictionary

Comment: You are welcome. There is no *build-in* dictionary within `PowerShell`. But for your purpose, a hashtable should fit as well. The only different I know is that the hashtable is not typesafe whereas you can specify a dictionary to use a string as the key (and value). If you need that, you can create a `.net` dictionary using `New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[System.String,System.String]"`. But I doubt you need it.

Comment: Jisaak, thanks for the quick response. Actually I want to try Dictionary. I'm getting syntax error. Can you please tel me what I'm missing here,$xml= New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[System.String,System.String]
$xml.SelectNodes("descendant::node()") | ? Value | % { @{$_.ParentNode = $_.Value}  }.. Thank you

Comment: Actually can you give me the complete script please? I'm little confused to update this.

Comment: Im not at home right now, I will post you a full example tomorrow. I would still use a hashtable with PowerShell.

Comment: Sure. Thank you so much.

Comment: I updated my answer with the promised dictionary script. I had to invoke `ToString()` on `$_.ParentNode` since its a `XmlElement`.

Comment: I'm executing following script, But the output is empty. 
@@@@@
$myDictionary = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[System.String,System.String]"
$xml = [xml] (Get-Content "C:\Deploy.config")     
$xml.SelectNodes("descendant::node()") | ? Value | % { $myDictionary.Add($_.ParentNode.ToString(), $_.Value) }

Comment: Yes, the output is empty because you are now storing the result into `$myDictionary` if you just add a new line with `$myDictionary` or if you mark `$myDictionary`within PowerShell ISE and press F8, you will see the output.

Comment: @jiassk,
Great. Working fine. Thank you so much

Comment: Well, I would still use a simple hashtable for that. But its your choice. If your question is answered, please mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: Ooops. I forgot. Sorry. I have accepted your answer. I was suggested to use dictionary, so I'm using dictionary. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you see the comment here.